# To call props from an const object in react native/expo

Tags: react-native, object, expo

I'm trying to figure out how to use const objects to create 3 categories in my trivia game. I'm defining each one of them like this:

```
const questions = [
{
    question: "Qual o tipo de arquitetura utilizada na Igreja da Madre de Deus?",
    answers: [
        { id: "1", text: "Colonial" },
        { id: "2", text: "Maneirista" },
        { id: "3", text: "Gótico" },
        { id: "4", text: "Barroco", correct: true }
    ]
}, 
{
    question: "No século XIX, o pintor que pintou os painéis da igreja foi:",
    answers: [
        { id: "1", text: "Sebastião Canuto da Silva Tavares", correct: true },
        { id: "2", text: "Frans Janszoon Post" },
        { id: "3", text: "Oscar Pereira da Silva" },
        { id: "4", text: "João de Deus Sepúlveda" }
    ],
    quiz_answer: "Esse é o cara!"
} 
]
export default questions;
```

There is a file called IndexQuiz, where I'm calling them through a menu of categories (inside TouchableOpacity):

```
export default ({ navigation }) => (
<ScrollView>
<SafeAreaView style={{alignItems: "center", flexDirection: "column"}}>

  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
    navigation.navigate("Quiz", {
      title: "Arquitetura",
      questions: arquitetura,
      color: "rgb(32, 53, 70)"
    })} 
    style={DesafiosStyles.cardContainer}>
  </TouchableOpacity>

  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
    navigation.navigate("Quiz", {
      title: "Curiosidades",
      questions: curiosidades,
      color: "rgb(32, 53, 70)"
    })} 
    style={DesafiosStyles.cardContainer}>
  </TouchableOpacity>

  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
    navigation.navigate("Quiz", {
      title: "História",
      questions: historia,
      color: "rgb(32, 53, 70)"
    })} 
    style={DesafiosStyles.cardContainer}>
  </TouchableOpacity>

</SafeAreaView>
</ScrollView> 
);
```

But when it comes to the Quiz file, inside render I have this:

```
render() {
const questions = this.props.route.params.questions.length;
const question = questions[this.state.activeQuestionIndex];
//console.log(question);
return (
  <View
    style={[
      styles.container,
      { backgroundColor: this.props.route.params.color }
    ]}
  >
    <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safearea}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{question.question}</Text>

        <ButtonContainer>
          {answers.map(answer => (
              <Button
                key={answer.id}
                text={answer.text}
                onPress={() => this.answer(answer.correct)}
              />
            ))}
        </ButtonContainer>

      </View>

      <Text style={styles.text}>
        {`${this.state.correctCount}/${this.state.totalCount}`}
      </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
    <Alert
      correct={this.state.answerCorrect}
      visible={this.state.answered}
    />
  </View>
);
}
```

Every time I try to call any of these categories, I got the "undefined is not an object" exception. I've tried to import the files and the "questions" const itself, but it didn't work. As simple as that must be, I'm stuck in this (yep, I'm kinda slow and basically a newbie with react native lol):

```
        <Text style={styles.text}>{question.question}</Text>
        <ButtonContainer>
          {answers.map(answer => (
              <Button
                key={answer.id}
                text={answer.text}
                onPress={() => this.answer(answer.correct)}
              />
            ))}
        </ButtonContainer>
```

Without this code, it shows the counter: "this.state.correctCount}/${this.state.totalCount", but that's all. How can I call these questions and answers properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you try to get questions from `length` property, not from `questions` object itself:

```js
const questions = this.props.route.params.questions.length;
const question = questions[this.state.activeQuestionIndex];
```

Comment: Yes, I've changed that too. But even calling the object directly it keeps returning "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'questions.question')".

I'm calling it like this: const questions = questions;

I wonder if the problem isn't in IndexQuiz or in the way I'm exporting the 'questions' object from each file...